# ODI getting agent name and server

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I wanted to know if there is a method to get the Agent name and the server where it's running. I tried reading all the OdiGetInfo() material, but couldn't find anything helpful.
I need these informations since I have to do an ODI package that constantly check if an Agent and the server are up & running. 
I know it's possible to do that using a shell script, executed from the ODI package, but I wanted to know if there is another way to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Method to get Agent Name:** odiRef.getSession("AGENT_NAME")

**Method to get Server details:** odiRef.getInfo("DEST_JAVA_URL")

**Note:** DEST_JAVA_URL parameter returns the entire JDBC URL mentioned in Physical Data server.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried the second one, but I got the wrong server, or so it seems, since it gave me a different server, not the one where the agent is running (and I know for sure since I started the agent).